# Twitter API call retweets_of_me

Tags: twitter

Can I get the info from the twitter API call "statuses/retweets_of_me" that who retweeted me? Above call only returns the 20 most recent tweets by me which have been retweeted by "???"..

How to get this information? Obviously I'd like to know about the least RATE API Limit consuming way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-retweets

above api call will tell the retweeted details for the given status.

So in order to get full information to get "retweets of me".

first call statuses/retweetes_of_me to get the the status ids of me which were retweeted and then use the above method call (check the URL) to get the retweeted_details for the given tweet id.

Strange, as it clashes with the Rate Limit API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, the only thing I can figure out is to do user_timeline:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

with : include_rts = true  -- I dont think this works properly on 1.0, going to try it on 1.1

Getting the who part, you need to call:

for each tweet https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/id and check the user Only 15 per window.

See this thread for background...https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14145

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `count` optional parameter to return up to 200 retweets of you..

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweets_of_me.xml?count=200

These will be tweets of yours that have been retweeted by others.

Or am I misunderstanding what you are needing?  If so, can you explain a little more as to what data you are expecting to receive?

Comment: I simply want to know the user who retweeted my tweet :) Above api calls tell me about the tweet that was retweeted but doesn't tell me who was the user who actually retweeted.

Comment: new link is this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets_of_me    maximum count is 100